# argparse subparser exit_on_error

Tags: python, argparse

I want to disable `exit_on_error` for a parser and subparser, to prevent error messages:

```py
import argparse


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)
       
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers() 
   
    subcommand = subparsers.add_parser('subcommand')
    subcommand.add_argument('argument')
   
    try:
        arguments = parser.parse_args()
    except:
        parser.print_usage(std.stderr)
```

With no arguments (ie: no subparser invoked) it works as intended:

```sh
$ python3 main.py 
usage: main.py {subcommand} ...
```

But when I use a subcommand, it doesn't:

```sh
$ python3 main.py subcommand
usage: main.py subcommand [-h] argument
main.py subcommand: error: the following arguments are required: argument
usage: main.py {subcommand} ...
```

In this instance, I'd want it to print this instead:

```sh
$ python3 main.py subcommand
usage: main.py {subcommand} ...
```

I checked, and neither `add_subparsers` nor `add_parser` take an `exit_on_error` argument. How can I suppress printing those error messages?

Comment: `add-parser takes the same parameters as ArgumentParser

Comment: @hpaulj this was one of the things I tried first, it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: `exit_on_error` does not capture that kind of error, https://bugs.python.org/issue41255.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108632/unable-to-catch-exception-error-for-argparse